# PHP Project mixing scalar types

Tags: php

Does any know if PHP will deal with me using scalar type declarations in certain areas of a project and not in others? I am looking to use some third party libraries that do not implement PHP's scalar type declarations but I myself want to implement them.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, aren't PHP's scalar types just *string*, *int*, *float* and *bool*? How do you *not* implement them?

Comment: @CD001 the OP is asking about [type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). They were introduced in PHP 5 for classes, extended later to include arrays and callables and since PHP 7 they also include the scalar types.

Comment: If third party code does not use them, you can't simply use them in the code that somehow interacts with code that's not under your control

Comment: Then the answer is yes. The whole thing was thought with the sacrosanct BC in mind.

Comment: @axiac - oh, now the question makes sense ... of course, had I read it more carefully *\*whistles innocently\**

Comment: Type hinting is optional so feel free to use it or don't use it; I won't judge you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the PHP documentation on migrating from 5.6.x to 7.0.x http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php scalar type declarations and return type declarations are both mentioned in "New features" section and not the "Backward Incompatible Changes" section so I assume it will be safe to use provided the right types are passed to my classes.